# What happens when you throw an exception from within a catch statement?

Tags: vb.net

I'm looking at some code, and there is a `try/catch/finally` block in which the try block contains some logic and defines an exception type within an `else` clause and throws it if the application gets to that point. Within the catch block is simply the keyword `throw`. What exactly is happening when that `throw` statement gets executed? Is there a stack trace that's being logged somewhere? Will the error display out to the user in the browser window? Will the application just crash?

The code looks something like this.

```
Try
    If something then
        some logic
    Else
        Dim exception As specialException("some message")
        exception.Source = "source"
        Throw exception
    End If
Catch ex As specialException
    Throw
```

Comment: See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/throw-statement): `Throw` on its own rethrows the exception without changing the stack trace.

Comment: When you use `Throw`, what happens is exactly what happens if you don't catch the exception in the first place (whatever that is, _depending on the situation_). Using `Throw ex` instead, will cause the same effect _except_ that the stack trace will be altered (think of it as a _new_ exception being thrown).

Answer (score 1):

It's passing the exception up to the next handler. If there is a try...catch block around the method call in which the exception is caught and thrown, it will be picked up and processed by that handler instead. Any stack trace logging or error displaying will have to be done there.

If there is no try...catch block, you will have an unhandled exception on your hands.